# Explanation of the associativity of nested conditional operators

Tags: conditional-operator

I do know that conditional operators have right associativity, but can't understand how the flow of `condition1` , `condition2` , `expression1` , `expression2` , `expression3` are all happening one after another. Or how the evaluation and flows are changing when we assume that associativity is left to right.

```
(condition1) ? (expression1) : ((condition2) ? (expression2) : (expression3)) ;
```

I asked Gemini and Copilot for an explanation, and they keep repeating the same thing: that `condition1` is the rightmost expression, but couldn't understand how. Or how and why `condition1` is the first one to get evaluated, irrespective of right or left associativity.

Comment: [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll assume you're referring to the conditional operator in the [C family of programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages). Tag your question with a specific language if you want to focus on that language.)

### Case 1: Base case

Let's start with the simplest case, a single conditional expression:

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

To evaluate this expression, follow these steps:

1. Evaluate `condition`.
2. If the result of Step 1 is true (or "truthy", depending on the language), then ignore `expression2` and evaluate `expression1`.
3. If the result of Step 1 is false (or "falsy", depending on the language), then ignore `expression1` and evaluate `expression2`.
4. Return the result of Step 2 (the value of `expression1`) or Step 3 (the value of `expression2`), whichever applies.

Notice that the order of evaluation goes from left to right: `condition` is evaluated first, followed by either `expression1` or `expression2`.

### Case 2: `condition` is a conditional expression

If the `condition` in `condition ? expression1 : expression2` is itself a conditional expression, then you get the following overall expression:

```
(subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2) ? expression1 : expression2
```

To evaluate this expression, follow the same steps as in the base case but  replace `condition` with `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2`. In Step 1, you'll *recurse*:

1. Evaluate `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2`. To do this, follow the same steps as in the base case:

   1. Evaluate `subcondition`.
   2. If the result of Step 1.1 is true, then ignore `subexpression2` and evaluate `subexpression1`.
   3. If the result of Step 1.1 is false, then ignore `subexpression1` and evaluate `subexpression2`.
   4. Return the result of Step 1.2 (the value of `subexpression1`) or Step 1.3 (the value of `subexpression2`), whichever applies.
2. If the result of Step 1 is true, then ignore `expression2` and evaluate `expression1`.
3. If the result of Step 1 is false, then ignore `expression1` and evaluate `expression2`.
4. Return the result of Step 2 (the value of `expression1`) or Step 3 (the value of `expression2`), whichever applies.

Notice that the order of evaluation goes from left to right: `subcondition` is evaluated first, followed by either `subexpression1` or `subexpression2`, followed by either `expression1` or `expression2`.

### Case 3: `expression2` is a conditional expression

If the `expression2` in `condition ? expression1 : expression2` is itself a conditional expression, then you get the following overall expression:

```
condition ? expression1 : (subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2)
```

To evaluate this expression, follow the same steps as in the base case but replace `expression2` with `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2`. In Step 3, you'll *recurse*:

1. Evaluate `condition`.
2. If the result of Step 1 is true, then ignore `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2` and evaluate `expression1`.
3. If the result of Step 1 is false, then ignore `expression1` and evaluate `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2`. To do this, follow the same steps as in the base case:

   1. Evaluate `subcondition`.
   2. If the result of Step 3.1 is true, then ignore `subexpression2` and evaluate `subexpression1`.
   3. If the result of Step 3.1 is false, then ignore `subexpression1` and evaluate `subexpression2`.
   4. Return the result of Step 3.2 (the value of `subexpression1`) or Step 3.3 (the value of `subexpression2`), whichever applies.
4. Return the result of Step 2 (the value of `expression1`) or Step 3 (the value of `subcondition ? subexpression1 : subexpression2`), whichever applies.

Notice that the order of evaluation goes from left to right: `condition` is evaluated first, followed by either `expression1` or `subcondition`, followed by (in the `subcondition` case only) either `subexpression1` or `subexpression2`.

### Left versus right associativity

Now let's look at your original expression, but omitting all parentheses:

```
condition1 ? expression1 : condition2 ? expression2 : expression3
```

This could potentially be interpreted in two different ways:

1. Left associative: `(condition1 ? expression1 : condition2) ? expression2 : expression3`

   - This is Case 2 above.
2. Right associative: `condition1 ? expression1 : (condition2 ? expression2 : expression3)`

   - This is Case 3 above.

An important thing to understand is that *associativity* and *order of evaluation* are two completely different concepts. For the conditional operator, left or right associativity simply determines whether you're in Case 2 or Case 3. But in both cases, the order of evaluation goes from left to right, with `condition1` evaluated first.